# Function in R to obtain mean on cumulative sum of several replicates

Tags: r

My data:

| treatment | replicate | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lo | A | Jan1 | 0 |
| lo | B | Jan1 | 3 |
| hi | A | Jan1 | 1 |
| hi | B | Jan1 | 7 |
| lo | A | Jan2 | 2 |
| lo | B | Jan2 | 7 |
| hi | A | Jan2 | 11 |
| hi | B | Jan2 | 1 |
| lo | A | Jan3 | 1 |
| lo | B | Jan3 | 0 |
| hi | A | Jan3 | 45 |
| hi | B | Jan3 | 8 |

What I would like to create an R function to do, is sum the values for each date across replicates, then take the mean. For each additional date, I would take the cumulative sum of that date plus the previous, and divide by the number of replicates, and so on. If that is confusing, the following will make it clear what I'm trying to do--this is what I would like as an output:

| treatment | date | value |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lo | Jan1 | 1.5 | <- (0+3 = 3; 3/2 = 1.5) |
| hi | Jan1 | 4 | <- (1+7 = 8; 8/2 = 4) |
| lo | Jan2 | 6 | <- (0+3+2+7 = 12; 12/2 = 6) |
| hi | Jan2 | 10 | <- (1+7+11+1 = 20; 20/2 = 10) |
| lo | Jan3 | 6.5 | <- (0+3+2+7+1+0 = 13; 13/2 = 6.5) |
| hi | Jan3 | 36.5 | <- (1+7+11+1+45+8 = 73; 73/2 = 36.5) |

I have tried this code:

```
require(plyr)


data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames){
  require(plyr)
  summary_func <- function(x, col){
    c(sum = sum(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
      se = (sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE)) / sqrt(sum(!is.na(x[[col]]))))
  }
  data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                  varname)
  data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("sum" = varname))
  return(data_sum)
}

output <- data_summary(data, varname="value", groupnames=c("treatment","replicate","date"))
```

and this give me the mean of the cumulative sum across dates, but then I need the mean for each date (with the previous dates totals added on), and I can't think of a solution.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think your table formatting is messed up and as a result I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you give us some code that makes your dummy dataframe so that we can try out your function? EDIT just saw you're still working on the post. example code for the table would still be cool!

Comment: Thanks for you comment @mandmeier! MrFlick edited my post to fix the formatting. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

in Base R:

```
transform(aggregate(value~treatment+date,dd,mean),
          value = ave(value, treatment, FUN=cumsum))

  treatment date value
1        hi Jan1   4.0
2        lo Jan1   1.5
3        hi Jan2  10.0
4        lo Jan2   6.0
5        hi Jan3  36.5
6        lo Jan3   6.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That worked great. Is there a way to also get standard error for each week, where the the first dates value is added to the second dates, and then standard error is taken, then the first, second, and third dates are added together and then the standard error taken, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` in two steps. First the mean, then the cumulative sum

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  summarize(value = mean(value), .by=c(treatment, date)) %>%
  mutate(value = cumsum(value), .by=c(treatment))
#   treatment date value
# 1        lo Jan1   1.5
# 2        hi Jan1   4.0
# 3        lo Jan2   6.0
# 4        hi Jan2  10.0
# 5        lo Jan3   6.5
# 6        hi Jan3  36.5
```

with sample data

```
dd <- structure(list(treatment = c("lo", "lo", "hi", "hi", "lo", "lo", 
"hi", "hi", "lo", "lo", "hi", "hi"), replicate = c("A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), date = c("Jan1", 
"Jan1", "Jan1", "Jan1", "Jan2", "Jan2", "Jan2", "Jan2", "Jan3", 
"Jan3", "Jan3", "Jan3"), value = c(0L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 45L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Alternatively you can do

```
dd %>% 
  group_by(treatment, date) %>% 
  summarize(value = mean(value)) %>%
  mutate(value = cumsum(value))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It seems like the perfect solution. When I try it, I get the message `Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `.by = c(treatment)`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_mutate()`:
! object 'treatment' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: I put the `dput` for the data I test with. Did you use `group_by` at all on your data? Are you sure it has a column named "treatment" like the sample data does? Hard to say what could be different without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I copied and pasted your "dd" dataframe, and I still get the same error 'treatment' not found. Which is weird, because if I get, ` dd$treatment
 [1] "lo" "lo" "hi" "hi" "lo" "lo" "hi" "hi" "lo" "lo" "hi" "hi"` , so it definitely is a variable in that dataframe that should be recognized. I tried restarting R and reloading the dpyler to no avail.

Comment: @user20214781 What version of dplyr are you running? The `.by=` stuff is newer. This should also work: `dd %>% group_by(treatment, date) %>% summarize(value = mean(value)) %>% mutate(value = cumsum(value))`

Comment: That was it! It works now. I'm on a locked down computer, so my dplyer is probably 6 months old at least. Thank you so much! You have been extremely helpful. I am very grateful!

Comment: Could I also calculate standard error using the pipes in dplyer? I'm thinking if I used the plotrix library and did something like: `dd %>% group_by(treatment, date) %>% summarize(value = mean(value), standard.error(value) %>% mutate(value = cumsum(value))`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

a1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~treatment, ~replicate,  ~date, ~value,
        "lo",        "A", "Jan1",     0L,
        "lo",        "B", "Jan1",     3L,
        "hi",        "A", "Jan1",     1L,
        "hi",        "B", "Jan1",     7L,
        "lo",        "A", "Jan2",     2L,
        "lo",        "B", "Jan2",     7L,
        "hi",        "A", "Jan2",    11L,
        "hi",        "B", "Jan2",     1L,
        "lo",        "A", "Jan3",     1L,
        "lo",        "B", "Jan3",     0L,
        "hi",        "A", "Jan3",    45L,
        "hi",        "B", "Jan3",     8L
  )
 
to_do <- map(1:3,
    \(x)head(unique(a1$date),n=x))

newdat <- map(to_do,\(d){
  a1 |> filter(date %in% d)
})

proc_df <- map_dfr(newdat, \(df){
  df |> group_by(treatment) |> summarise(date=max(date),
                                       value=sum(value)/length(unique(replicate))) |> ungroup()
})
proc_df
```

Comment: Thank you Nir Graham for your answer! That is super helpful. Is there a way to turn the output into a dataframe?

Comment: proc_df the output, is  data.frame. what is it for you?